# how to add user latitude and longitude values in arcgis.?

Tags: java, arcgis

I am using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java in my project. I need to add latitude/longitude values for GPS tracking. I can't find a solution to perform this. There are sample codes to perform this, but I think they are using a CSV file for the values.

I can't find a way to add a path of the CSV file or add a CSV file.

Sample code:

```
private static final String FSP = System.getProperty("file.separator");

private String getPathSampleData() {
    String dataPath = null;
    String javaPath = ArcGISRuntime.getInstallDirectory();
    if (javaPath != null) {
        if (!(javaPath.endsWith("/") || javaPath.endsWith("\\"))) {
            javaPath += FSP;
        }
        dataPath = javaPath + "sdk" + FSP + "samples" + FSP + "data" + FSP;
    }
    File dataFile = new File(dataPath);
    if (!dataFile.exists()) { 
        dataPath = ".." + FSP + "data" + FSP;
    }
    return dataPath;
}
```

Can any one help me to solve my issue?

Comment: You need to provide more information: what exactly is the problem, what have you tried, why the sample code is not satisfactory etc

Comment: The sample code you posted is the method from the ArcGIS Runtime SDK samples that returns the path to the SDK's sample data. It won't help you add a CSV to a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned both GPS and CSV, and I will explain how to use both of them in ArcGIS Runtime.

## GPS

Use the [`GPSLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/map/GPSLayer.html) class to display a location stream on the map. There are a few options for using `GPSLayer`:

1. Use a [`SerialPortGPSWatcher`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/core/gps/SerialPortGPSWatcher.html) to connect to a serial port (or virtual serial port) GPS ([sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/serial-port-gps/)).
2. Use a [`FileGPSWatcher`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/core/gps/FileGPSWatcher.html) to use an NMEA file of GPS points ([sample 1](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/gps-layer/), [sample 2](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/file-gps/)).
3. Implement the [`IGPSWatcher`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/core/gps/IGPSWatcher.html) interface to do something other than real GPS or an NMEA file, such as a CSV file.

## CSV

If what you really want is to display a CSV on the map, I can think of two options:

1. Parse the CSV yourself and put the results into a [`GraphicsLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/map/GraphicsLayer.html) ([sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/add-graphics/)). (There are 1,001 ways to parse a CSV in Java; if I were writing that code, `BufferedReader` and `StringTokenizer` would be my friends.)
2. Use the [`CSVLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/com/esri/map/CSVLayer.html) class. There aren't any samples and it's not very well documented, because it appears to have been written for internal use for displaying a CSV layer stored in a web map. But you can use it with a CSV file as follows:

   ```
   //map is of type JMap
   map.addMapEventListener(new MapEventListenerAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void mapReady(MapEvent event) {
           String layerDef = "{   \"geometryType\": \"esriGeometryPoint\",   \"type\": \"Feature Layer\",   \"typeIdField\": \"\",   \"drawingInfo\": {     \"renderer\": {       \"type\": \"simple\",       \"symbol\": {         \"type\": \"esriSMS\",         \"style\": \"esriSMSCircle\",         \"color\": [200, 40, 0, 255],         \"size\": 15,         \"angle\": 0,         \"xoffset\": 0,         \"yoffset\": 0       }     },     \"fixedSymbols\": true   },   \"fields\": [     {       \"name\": \"X\",       \"alias\": \"X\",       \"type\": \"esriFieldTypeDouble\",       \"editable\": true,       \"nullable\": true,       \"domain\": null     },     {       \"name\": \"Y\",       \"alias\": \"Y\",       \"type\": \"esriFieldTypeDouble\",       \"editable\": true,       \"nullable\": true,       \"domain\": null     }   ],   \"name\": \"My CSV Layer\" }";
           CSVLayer.CSVConfig csvConfig = new CSVLayer.CSVConfig();
           csvConfig.url = new File("/path/to/csv-file.csv").toURI().toString();
           csvConfig.columnDelimiter = ",";
           csvConfig.longitudeField = "X";
           csvConfig.latitudeField = "Y";
           try {
               final CSVLayer csvLayer = new CSVLayer(layerDef, csvConfig);
               map.getLayers().add(csvLayer);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               //Handle the exception
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Unfortunately, you do need that JSON string in order to use `CSVLayer`. I made the JSON string as simple as possible. You'll need to adjust it if your field names for longitude and latitude are not `X` and `Y`. You can see the [`layerDefinition` schema documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r30000004v000000) and a more elaborate example ([description](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/CSV_operational_layer/02r300000043000000/), [JSON](http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/items/46e0e5d85f49492787ce954f9ac1a7cb/data?f=pjson)).

The JSON string you need for option 2 makes option 1 the better choice in my opinion. Parsing a CSV is easy; managing that JSON string is harder.